# Erlang pattern matching with functions

Tags: function, erlang, pattern-matching

As Erlang is an almost pure functional programming language, I'd imagine this was possible:

```
case X of
    foo(Z) -> ...
end.
```

where `foo(Z)` is a *decidable-invertible* pure (side-effect free) bijective function, e.g.:

```
foo(input) -> output.
```

Then, in the case that `X = output`, `Z` would match as `input`.

Is it possible to use such semantics, with or without other syntax than my example, in Erlang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Erlang only supports literal patterns!

And your original request is not an easy one. Just because there is a an inverse doesn't mean that it is easy to find. Practically it would that the compiler would have to make two versions of functions.

Answer (score 4):

No, what you want is not possible.

To do something like this you would need to be able to find the inverse of any bijective function, which is obviously undecidable.

Comment: @Pindatjuh: I know what a bijective function is. But just because every bijective function has an inverse does not mean that you can write an algorithm to find it (you can't).

Comment: I'll edit the question: an invertible pure bijective function.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the reason why that is not allowed is that you want to guarantee the lack of side effects. Given the following structure:

```
case Expr of
    Pattern1 [when GuardSeq1] ->
        Body1;
    ...;
    PatternN [when GuardSeqN] ->
        BodyN
end
```

After you evaluate `Expr`, the patterns are sequentially matched against the result of `Expr`. Imagine your `foo/1` function contains a side effect (e.g. it sends a message):

```
foo(input) ->
  some_process ! some_msg,
  output.
```

Even if the first pattern wouldn't match, you would have sent the message anyway and you couldn't recover from that situation.

Comment: Thanks, however I meant with "pure function" that it is not allowed to have side-effects. I'll edit the question.

Comment: I understand that. The problem, though, is how to ensure the function is pure, when it is user-defined.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is:

```
Y = foo(Z),
case X of
  Y -> ...
end.
```

Comment: That requires you to know the value of Z though. I'm pretty sure that's not what the OP intended.

Comment: Well, if one replaces `foo` with `foo_inverse`, it makes sense. However, as sepp2k said, that's not what I intended.